# How to fix "Can't Play a Disabled Audio Source"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a sound into my game that whenever the player moves over a certain space it plays a crunch sound. I have created the AudioSource file and a .OGG file for the sound.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpaceBlue : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform spaceNext;
    public AudioSource stepOnObject;
    public AudioClip stepOnSound;

    private void Start()
    {
        stepOnObject.clip = stepOnSound;
        stepOnObject.enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            stepOnObject.Play();
            if (BoardScript.diceValue > 0)
            {
                BoardScript.diceValue -= 1;
                Debug.Log("The dice are now " +BoardScript.diceValue);
                other.transform.LookAt(spaceNext);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have included the source and clip to my game object and i have tried it both with and without "Play on wake" selected.

Whenever the play walks over the player walks over the object i get a warning in the unity engine saying that the source is disabled.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is the Audio Source component enabled? What about the gameobject it is attached to?

Comment: Yes they are both enabled

Comment: Make sure you haven't accidentally added multiple audio sources. If you haven't, then I'd say you should remove the audio source component from the object and re-add a new one to see if that works. If the issue still persists, then I would submit a bug report to Unity because it should work if everything is enabled.

Comment: Show a screenshot?

Comment: Brandon I am at work now but I will try your recommendation once I get back. If that doesn't work I'll post some screenshots Draco

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by changing the location of the Play() call to after calling Destroy(GameObject). I would recommend trying moving the call to Play() to the end of the function, or trying Invoke("stepOnObject.Play", 0.5f); to ensure it gets called.

Otherwise, make sure its checkbox is ticked, and that the AudioSource actually has a AudioClip attached.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any piece of code in some other script that Destroys this game object or makes SetActive false, then the best way to solve this problem will be  to delay that piece of code by some time using a Coroutine.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks!